# How to perform Fisher test in every subgroup

Tags: r, dataframe, crosstab

I have a dataframe with following data:

```
age.cat ds.cat  finalstate
<65     AGN     dead
<65     AGN     alive
<65     PC      alive
65+     AMI     alive
65+     PC      dead
<65     AMI     alive
```

For every level of `ds.cat` factor variable I need to perform Fisher test for `age.cat` and `finalstate` variables.

I tried to do it by several ways but was not received what I need. The following R code doesn't produce desired result:

```
library(descr)
# 1 syntax - doesn't work
by(split(df, df$ds.cat), CrossTable(age.cat, finalstate, prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE))
# 2 syntax - doesn't work
sapply( split(df, df$ds.cat), function(x) CrossTable(age.cat, finalstate, prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE) )
# 3 syntax - doesn't work
for(i in 1:nlevels(ds.cat)){
    curcat <- subset(df, ds.cat == ds.cat[i])
    CrossTable(age.cat[ds.cat == ds.cat[i]], finalstate[ds.cat == ds.cat[i]], prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE, data = curcat)
}
```

Please could anyone suggest how to perform Fisher test for `age.cat` and `finalstate` variables for every level of `ds.cat` factor variable?

### Resolved!

Thank you so much for all of you!

This code with `CrossTable` produces an error

```
Error in chisq.test(t, correct = FALSE) : 
'x' must at least have 2 elements
```

But thanks for @BenBolker the base `fisher.test` function works well in your code

```
l <- split(arf.mort, arf.mort$ds.cat)
lapply(l, function(x) fisher.test(x$age.cat, x$finalstate))
```

as well as works well

```
by(arf.mort, arf.mort$ds.cat, function(x){ fisher.test(x$age.cat, x$finalstate) })
```

Comment: reproducible example?  why are you using `CrossTable` (from some unknown package) rather than `fisher.test` from base R ?

Comment: @BenBolker, the package seems to be `gmodels` and they've credited *you* (or some other Ben Bolker, that must be an awesome coincidence) in their manual [**here**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmodels/gmodels.pdf)

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mentioned the package. It is descr library. Added to the question this important issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention the package you're using (`gmodels`). We don't know every package that have been developed. This seems to work and I think is what you're looking for.

```
require(gmodels)
l <- split(df, df$ds.cat)
lapply(l, function(x) CrossTable(x$age.cat, x$finalstate, 
            prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE)
```

It gives a whole bunch of tables (I guess its similar to S-plus format).

Comment: Thank you so much! The code with `CrossTable` produces an error, while `fisher.test` function works well. Put the solution to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you're working with the iris dataset(it's loaded when you start R), and you wanted to take the CrossTable of the first 2 columns, split by the Species.  This is how you do it:

```
#whatever a crosstable is
CrossTable <- function(x, y){
    #something tricky
    sum(x+y)
}

by(iris, iris$Species, function(x){ CrossTable(x[1], x[2]) })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code with `CrossTable` produces an error, while `fisher.test` function works well. Put the solution to the answer.